# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо выбрать список значений Item_ID с самой поздней (максимальной) датой, но при выполнении выдаётся ошибка ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Если переводить дословно, то она указывает на несоответствие количества скобок. Подскажите, что может быть не так?

```
select Item_ID
from Fact_Item_Price 
where "Date" = (select max (t."Date") from Fact_Item_Price t
group by t.Item_ID order by t.Item_ID);
```

Сам фрагмент выбора максимальной даты работает:

```
select max (t."Date") from Fact_Item_Price t
group by t.Item_ID order by t.Item_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Oracle подзапросах не может быть фразы `order by`, т.к. она там не имеет никакого смысла. В итоге Oracle ожидает увидеть правую скобку сразу после фразы `group by`, однако натыкается на слово `order` и на нем сообщает, что не нашел скобку.

Кроме этого после исправления у вас возникнет вторая ошибка: подзапрос вернет более одной строки, что недопустимо в случае использования оператора `=`, следует использовать `IN`.

```
select Item_ID
  from Fact_Item_Price 
 where "Date" IN (select max (t."Date") from Fact_Item_Price t
                   group by t.Item_ID)
```

Правда этот запрос вероятно сделает не то, что вы хотели. Вы задаете `group by Item_ID` и берете таким образом для каждого Item_ID максимальную дату. Но для любого Item_ID найдется максимальная дата, в итоге вы получите полный список Item_ID из вашей таблицы. Поэтому, если вам нужны Item_ID с одинаковой, но самой большой в таблице датой - то следует убрать `group by`, либо заменить его на какой то, более отвечающий вашей задаче.

Comment: Без `group by` заработало. Но проблема в том, что `select` в скобках возвращает 3 значения дат (они действительно максимальные), а первый `select` операцией `where "Date" IN` выбирает 4 значения.

Comment: @NickAviator Если вы убрали group by то запрос вернет гарантированно одну строку (по чисто техническим причинам, что две разные даты не могут быть обе максимальные), вы что то не договариваете. Если же все таки вы там записи как то группируете, что получаете 3 даты, то почему бы в БД не быть двум Item_ID с одинаковой датой равной этой максимальной ?

Comment: Извиняюсь что ввёл в заблуждение, я имел в виду без `order by`. Нет, 2 даты разные, возможно для этого придётся создать доп. условия.
Тем не менее, спасибо за разъяснения что к чему в Oracle.